# Why are my dc-js axes showing up so thick and brush filter appearing opaque black?

Tags: javascript, css, dc.js

I'm having trouble with axes on some dc-js plots.
The axis lines are overly-thick and brush-filters are appearing as black boxes.
For example, the lower portion of the attached figure is drawn with only the following commands:

```
lower_bar_chart
    .height(100)
    .dimension(week_dim) // a basic time-rounded-to-the-week dimension
    .group(count_by_week_group) // counts of some events by week
    .centerBar(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2010, 01, 01), new Date(2015, 01, 01)]))
    .round(d3.time.week.round)
    .alwaysUseRounding(true)
    .xUnits(d3.time.weeks);
```

This is nearly identical to the Nasdaq dc-js example, but the rendering looks awful (not to mention the opaque black time brush selections).
Any idea what might be going on?
I figured it was a style issue, but I'm already including dc.css.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. dc.css wasn't being served up by the CDN correctly... downloading a local copy fixed the issue.

Comment: That's good to know.  Please accept your own answer, once the 48 hours are up.  Also, which CDN?  cdnjs?

Comment: Yeah, for any future visitors with a similar issue, it's almost certainly that dc.css isn't being loaded correctly. I was using cdnjs.buttflare.com, but since this post that CDN seems to be working again.